# Show previous valid value of h:selectOneListbox when invalid selection is made

Tags: validation, jsf, select, listbox

I have a problem with the validation of a selectOneListBox. Everything works fine and a message is displayed, when the input is false. But the dropdown keeps the selected value as the dropdown value. I want to display the old value if validation fails.
So how can I do that?

I tried this:

```
<h:selectOneListbox id="intFrom" value="#{searchBean.intFrom}" size="1" immediate="true" class="intSelectBox1">
                 <f:ajax render=":menuForm :searchForm:searchButton" listener="#{menuBean.focus(menuBean.mySearch)}" />
                 <f:ajax listener="#{searchBean.count()}" render="int1" />
                 <f:ajax execute="intFrom" render="intFrom" />
                 <f:selectItems value="#{searchBean.intRangeFrom}" />
                 <f:validator validatorId="project.IntFromValidator" />
              </h:selectOneListbox>
              <h:message id="int1" for="intFrom" style="color: red" />
```

But after that the new value is being displayed not the old one.

Comment: It is correct behavior: user select wrong value - message is displayed. If you reset value to previous, the message will not be relevant with displayed information. For example: empty field changed to same value and you inform user that selected value is incorrect, but user cannot to see what is selected. You can add Cancel button which reset all fields to previous values (without error messages).